# NSObject Decodable same value

Tags: swift

**JSON:**

```
{
   "words": "1"
}
```

some times the key  `words` or `word`

when parse this JSON,it is fail with following error

**Error:**

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "paragraph", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"paragraph\", intValue: nil) (\"paragraph\").", underlyingError: nil)). paragraph is the words

```
@objcMembers class EmphasisModel: NSObject ,Codable{
    var words:String?
}
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case word,words
}

required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    self.words = try container.decode(String?.self, forKey: .words)

    if self.words != nil {
            self.words = try container.decode(String?.self, forKey: .word)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `decodeIfPresent` while `decoding`. The `if statement` is wrong. It should check for equal to nil instead of non-nil.

```
class EmphasisModel: Decodable {

    var words: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case word, words
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        self.words = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .words)

        if self.words == nil {
            self.words = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .word)
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
let data = """
          { "words": "1" }
         """.data(using: .utf8)!
do {
    let ad = try JSONDecoder().decode(EmphasisModel.self, from: data)
    print(ad?.words)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```